# Select all rows of MySql table with value is greater than to zero (decimal type)

Tags: mysql

On the table `dotable` of MySQL database 8.0.12 version I have set this decimal field

```
Num_cl decimal(10,5)
```

The table contains this data

```
+-------+--------+
| id    | Num_cl |
+-------+--------+
| 46777 | 1,00   |
| 46778 | 0,00   |
| 46779 | 1,00   |
| 46780 | 1,00   |
| 46781 | 0,00   |
+-------+--------+
```

I need select all rows of `dotable` with `Num_cl` value is greater than to zero

I have tried this query

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Num_cl 
FROM
    dotable 
WHERE 
    CONVERT (Num_cl, SIGNED INTEGER) > 0;
```

the return is `Empty set`

How to do resolve this?

**Table structure for dotable**

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for dotable
-- ----------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dotable`;
CREATE TABLE `dotable`  (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Num_cl` decimal(10, 5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES (46777, 1.00);
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES (46778, 0.00);
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES (46779, 1.00);
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES (46780, 1.00);
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES (46781, 0.00);
```

**update**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dotable`;
CREATE TABLE `dotable`  (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Num_cl` decimal(10, 5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES (46777, 1.00);
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES (46778, 0.00);
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES (46779, 1.00);
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES (46780, 1.00);
INSERT INTO `dotable` VALUES (46781, 0.00);

SELECT
    ID,
    Num_cl 
FROM
    dotable 
WHERE 
    CONVERT (Num_cl, SIGNED INTEGER) > 0;

+-------+---------+
| ID    | Num_cl  |
+-------+---------+
| 46777 | 1.00000 |
| 46779 | 1.00000 |
| 46780 | 1.00000 |
+-------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Please add the result of show create table <tablename>

Comment: @P.Salmon Pls see **Table structure for dotable** in the question, thks

Comment: Sure you got things the right way round?

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry... error on the table dotable, pls see **update**  on the question

Comment: Works find on 8.0.22. What version of MySQL are you running??

Comment: Well ,what is your expected result ? I see your select query does return correct output.

Comment: @DaveStokes thanks solved, error on the table dotable structure...

Comment: @Dev-vruper thanks solved, error on the table dotable structure...